# How can I install both 32 and 64 bit versions of the same -dev package?

Tags: installation, apt, 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

I'm trying to install `libsqlite3-dev` for both `i386` and `amd64` on the same Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I'm developing an application that uses sqlite3, and want to compile and test both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

However it looks like the `libsqlite3-dev:i386` package is incompatible with the `libsqlite3-dev:amd64`, as `apt` keeps wanting to remove one when I install the other.

Is there a way to get both installed on the same system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot install both of the -dev packages on the same system at the same time. You can only install one or the other, as they contain some of the same files. Multi-arch doesn't enable cross-compilation support, which is what you're trying to do. If you were to install the `:i386` version of the sqlite development package, and build with the 64-bit compiler, you'll almost certainly have a broken build as a result.

Your best bet is to compile in a 32-bit chroot or VM, to build the 32-bit version.

Comment: The header files are indeed in both packages, but their contents is identical. Even more, for other `-dev` packages such as `zlib1g` which also have shared (and identical) files, it _is_ possible to install both version simultaneously.

Comment: I just force-installed both packages, this didn't seem to break anything and I can now build (and run correctly) both versions. Is this just a case of the package maintainer declaring a conflict where there isn't really one?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do not consider forced installations even as a last resort. I think, you might find pbuilder quite useful. Here's a HOWTO for that. You can even install different distros for that purpose, and script the building process for different targets at the same time.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=206382

So, you can even leave all the dev packages uninstalled. They get installed into that temporary chroot installation.