# How to install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of package?

Tags: multiarch

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386
```

It removes `libcurl4-openssl-dev` package and vice-versa.
How can I install both versions, for building both 32-bit and 64-bit version, of my program on one machine?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Try MultiArch it works for you
[enter link description here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch#Installing)

Comment: I need this to build both versions on my build machine

Comment: Can someone explain how MultiArch works? Why instead of installing somePackage:amd64 and somePackage:i386 I need to install some magic metapackage that contains 32bit versions of some libs? What if ia32-libs-multiarch doesnt contain 32bit library I need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install both 32 and 64 bit versions of the same -dev package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254754/how-can-i-install-both-32-and-64-bit-versions-of-the-same-dev-package)